# TypeScript declare const from Node (fs, child_process etc.)

Tags: node.js, typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

Basically my problem is that I have created a global constant variable for Node's FileSystem Api in JavaScript (!!! this is important) like so:

```
const FS = require('fs');
```

It is in fact working fine if after this in my TypeScript files I use this:

```
declare const FS;
```

But like this VSCode is not showing any kind of information when I type `FS` except the fact that it exists. And why would it do so? (It's a separate file that is not even TypeScript)

Thanks to DefinetlyTyped I have though the declaration file for all of Node's modules.

So my question is:

Is there a way to reference my declared constant to Node's FileSystem via the declaration file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will let you use intellisense as you want

```
/// <reference path="../typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />
import * as fs from "fs";
```

Also if not installed yes then install typing node with typings

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!
The problem with this is that thanks to SystemJS (which is important in my project, if I use CommonJS it works) I get this error:
Failed to load resource: chrome-extension://cfhhebiikkbpfnohghbajopmpigeaffo/fs

Comment: I just edited my comment, please check it back (I accidentally tapped Enter instead of Shift + Enter)

Comment: have you typing installed in your project?

Comment: Yes I do with Node and other definitions. :/

Comment: And the intellisense actually sees that it is the node filesystem but after the compilation I get that error in the console

Comment: If i use the code that you provided up there, yes it works

Comment: Isn't there a way of importing as a declaration or something like that?

Comment: Note: fs is for beckend and can't work in browser. then please accept the answer as it resolved your original query :-)

Comment: Ok I will resolve it and ask it again as the Holy Editor removed the important parts of my post that declared that this is an NW.js app with angular so it should work like that :D